# Apache mod_rewrite mod_proxy redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, puppet, mod-proxy, theforeman

I am trying to redirect /foreman to https://someurl:4343

I am using:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass  /foreman https://MyIP:4343/
ProxyPassReverse  /foreman https://MyIP:4343/
```

Results so far are that:

- I get the index page with no style and no images
- none of the links work i.e. /foreman/hosts?somevariable=somevalue

I would like to get all requests to /foreman/* to go to https://MyIP:4343/* including variables, get requests, images, style sheet, etc

How should I proceed ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `SSLProxyEngine on` before your `ProxyPass` declaration? See [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/84821/apache-proxypass-with-ssl) for related issue

Comment: Trailing slash on `/foreman/`?  The [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) say `If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing / and vice versa. Otherwise the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.`

Comment: yeah .. I tried every combination to no avail

Answer (score 1):

This was a clueless noob moment.

I found out that my desired outcome can be resolved with mod_ruby

I used the below link for a guide to the resolution to my issue.

[Foreman as Sub-URI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri)

Answer (score 0):

You need the trailing slash on /foreman 
ProxyPass  /foreman/ https://MyIP:4343/
ProxyPassReverse  /foreman/ https://MyIP:4343/